# Are two Indestructible creatures safe from each other, or do they somehow cancel each other out and destroy each other?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-indestructible

My friend attacked with [Colossus of Akros](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Colossus%20of%20Akros) (Monstrous 20/20 indestructible) and I blocked with my [Xenagos, God of Revels](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Xenagos%2C%20God%20of%20Revels) (6/5 indestructible). I believe that our creatures are safe since indestructible prevents them from dying by combat damage.

My friend though believes that the indestructible ability would cancel each other out and his Colossus would destroy my Xenagos. Are there any rules that explains what happens in this situation?

Comment: Note that Colossus of Akros has trample when it is Monstrous, so you're still taking 15 damage from that hit.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Oh it does, I guess we both overlooked that part of the monstrous ability.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, nothing like your friend's idea happens. Indestructible simply means they can't be destroyed, period. They can be exiled, returned to their owner's hand, sacrificed, have their toughness reduced to zero, shuffled into their owner's library, or even turned into frogs, but if anything tries to destroy them, including lethal damage, it just doesn't happen.

> 702.12b A permanent with indestructible can’t be destroyed. Such permanents aren't destroyed by lethal damage, and they ignore the state-based action that checks for lethal damage (see rule 704.5g).

There's no secret "...unless..." clause in the rules like your friend believes. The only way to actually *destroy* an indestructible creature is to make it stop being indestructible; usually that means causing it to lose all its abilities, like if you [turn it into a frog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=398463)!

Comment: Also worth noting that they can be turned into frogs and then destroyed, as usually when they're frogs they lose "indestructible".

Comment: I meant that they can't be destroyed when I said "our creatures are safe" but thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @JohnOdom I know, and that's what my answer is confirming, just with more rules-ish language. When I said "no" I meant to what your friend said.

Comment: Don't forget that indestructible creatures can also be removed by reducing toughness to 0 or less, or being moved to any other zone, such as the library or phase out zone (bounce and exile are only 2 zones).

Comment: Okay, I added those things, but really, I don't think this answer needs to contain a comprehensive list of every last way a permanent can "go away" besides being destroyed. The point is that it can't be destroyed. Yes, you could also keep them from attacking/blocking, you could take control of them, you could turn them over with Ixidron, phase them out with Sapphire Charm... but that's not really the question that needed answering here.

Comment: @user777 Also, not that I believe that phasing really matters anymore, but there is no "phase out zone". Phasing out is a *status*, not a zone change. A phased out object remains in the zone it was already in, but you pretend it doesn't exist.